# Как исправить ошибку в программе?

Tags: java

Почему программа даже при правильных ответах ставит оценку 2(1) и говорит 
"Правильных ответов - 0, неправильных ответов 7". Как это исправить?

```
//импорт сканнера
import java.util.Scanner;
public class English_dialog_2a {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Переменные с речью
    String Cathy1 = "Tony! Come in!";
    String Tony1 = "Hi, Cathy. How are you?";
    String Cathy2 = "I'm fine thanks. How about you?";
    String Tony2 = "Fine";
    String Cathy3 = "I'd like to introduse you to Jim";
    String Tony3 = "Hello Jim. Pleased to meet you";
    String Jim1 = "Pleaset to meet you, too";
    //Экземпляр класса Сканнер
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Ввод запомненной человеком речи
    System.out.println("Речь Кетти");
    String cathy1 = scanner.nextLine();
    String cathy2 = scanner.nextLine();
    String cathy3 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Речь Тони");
    String tony1 = scanner.nextLine();
    String tony2 = scanner.nextLine();
    String tony3 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Речь Джима");
    String jim1 = scanner.nextLine();
    //Переменные с баллами
    int a = 0; // Правильные ответы
    int b = 0; // Неправильные ответы
    //Проверка
    if (cathy1 != Cathy1){
        b++;
        System.out.println("Неправильно(Cathy1)");
    }
    else{
        a++;
        System.out.println("Правильно(Cathy1)");
    }
    if (cathy2 != Cathy2){
        b++;
        System.out.println("Неправильно(Cathy2)");
    }
    else{
        a++;
        System.out.println("Правильно(Cathy2)");
    }
    if (cathy3 != Cathy3){
        b++;
        System.out.println("Неправильно(Cathy3)");
    }
    else{
        a++;
        System.out.println("Правильно(Cathy3)");
    }
    if (tony1 != Tony1){
        b++;
        System.out.println("Неправильно(Tony1)");
    }
    else{
        a++;
        System.out.println("Правильно(Tony1)");
    }
    if (tony2 != Tony2){
        b++;
        System.out.println("Неправильно(Tony2)");
    }
    else {
        a++;
        System.out.println("Правильно(Tony2)");
    }
    if(tony3 != Tony3){
        b++;
        System.out.println("Неправильно(Tony3)");
    }
    else{
        a++;
        System.out.println("Правильно(Tony3)");
    }
    if (jim1 != Jim1){
        b++;
        System.out.println("Неправильно(Jim1)");
    }
    else{
        a++;
        System.out.println("Правильно(Jim1)");
    }
    // Проверка баллов и выставление оценок
    if (b == 0){
        System.out.println("Оценка - 5");
    }

    if (b == 1){
        System.out.println("Оценка - 5");
    }
    if (b == 2){
        System.out.println("Оценка - 4");
    }
    if (b == 3){
        System.out.println("Оценка - 4");
    }
    if (b == 4){
        System.out.println("Оценка - 3");
    }
    if (b == 5){
        System.out.println("Оценка - 3");
    }
    if (b == 6){
        System.out.println("Оценка - 2");
    }
    if (b == 7){
        System.out.println("Оценка - 2 (1)");
    }
    //Вывод  результатов на экран
    System.out.println("Правильные ответы - " + a + "," + " неправильные ответы - " + b + ".");
}
}
```

Comment: `String` нельзя сравнивать по `==`, нужен `equals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сравнении строк используйте метод `equals`, например:

```
if (!cathy1.equals(Cathy1)){
        b++;
        System.out.println("Неправильно(Cathy1)");
}
```

P.S. Не используйте в Java переменные с именем, начинающиеся с большой буквы